# problem with width:50% when border != none (CSS)

Tags: html, css, width, border

problem with width:50% when border != none

take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/5nYSf/

result should be like this

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put two elements beside each other that are 50% wide, then you can put another element inside each that has to margin and border: http://jsfiddle.net/5nYSf/47/

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

There is a easy way:
add { box-sizing: border-box; } in .attachments
and the 50% width will contain the border too

Comment: no additional element required, this is the correct answer as of today. Demo and explanation can bee seen here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing. 
And old IE used to behaves that box-sizing: border-box

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, border and margin are not included in height/width calculation. So, if you have element with width 100px, border 2px and left margin 10px, the 114px of horizontal space will be taken up. (Border is counted twice: left and right.) IIRC, padding is not included too, but I'm not sure about that.

There're several options to solve this. You can have `width:49%` on both elements or `width:50%` on first and make second to take up the rest.
If both elements must take exactly equal space, you can include each in its own `div`. Those divs will have no border/margin/padding and take up exactly 50% of space and border will be specified on inner element.

The last method in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/5nYSf/35/

Answer (score 1):

If your borders are a fixed width you  could substract the border lenght from your element width using the calc() function in your CSS.

```
.attachments {
height:80px;    
background-color:#E4E4E4;
}

.attachments span {
float:left;
height:100%;
width:calc(50% - 6px);
background-color:#9FB9CA;
border:3px #879AA8 solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5nYSf/277/

Answer (score 0):

Border is in addition to the defined width, so 50% + 50% + 3px border (on both sides) ends up being 100% + 12px, which is 12px bigger than the containing element (100%).  Try using 49% or some other measurement that will leave 12px for the border.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to factor in those margins (to show up light grey areas) and that you can't use height:100% for the same reasons you can't use width:50% (as described by others here)

Answer (score 0):

the border expands the box.

50% + border > 50%

you have to decrease the width:

```
.attachments {
    height:80px;    
    background-color:#E4E4E4;
}

.attachments span {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:48%;
    background-color:#9FB9CA;
    border:3px #879AA8 solid;
}
```